# C#/WPF: How can I from a ViewModel find out what is Selected in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can I from a `ViewModel`, find out what is the selected text? What I am doing wanting to accomplish is similar to the WMD Markdown Editor here on StackOverflow when you bold/format text. Work on the selected text and modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem right for you to manage the selection in the ViewModel, that should not contain functionality, only business data.
But in any case:

Bind the SelectionChanged event for the textbox:

```
<TextBox SelectionChanged="TextBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

And then handle the selection in whatever way you find pleasant:

```
private void TextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string thisIsTheSelectedText = ((TextBox) sender).SelectedText;
}
```

Or bind it twoway to a property on the ViewModel:

```
<TextBox SelectedText="{Binding MyModelProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: I decided to encapsulate such functionality into a user control + `RoutedCommands`, it think it should be better.